# How can I detect a "certificate-error" message in an electron app?

Tags: electron, client-certificates

I have an Electron app. Running fine.

I add the following function in to main.ts:

```
function MakeHTTPCall(url:string, id:string)
{
  var request = require('request');

  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': url,
    'headers': {
    'Cookie': ''
    }
  };

  options.headers["Cookie"] = 'ID=' + id;
  
  request(options, function (error:any, response:any) {
    if (error){
      throw new Error(error);
    } 

    var s = response;

  })
}
```

This code currently lands on the "throw new Error" line. When I look at the error text it is:

```
code:'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
message:'self signed certificate in certificate chain'
stack:'Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain\n    at TLS
```

After doing a web search I added this to my main.ts code:

```
app.on ("certificate-error", (event, webContents, url, error, cert, callback) => {
    // Do some verification based on the URL to not allow potentially malicious certs:
    if (url.startsWith ("https://yourdomain.tld")) {
        // Hint: For more security, you may actually perform some checks against
        // the passed certificate (parameter "cert") right here
        
        event.preventDefault (); // Stop Chromium from rejecting the certificate
        callback (true);         // Trust this certificate
    } else callback (false);     // Let Chromium do its thing
});
```

But this code is never called.

How can I get it to fire? I just want to see if I can ignore the error and make the HTML call.

Thanks

Comment: `I just want to see if I can ignore the error` Never do that, certificate errors are there for a reason. Try to fix the error instead so that it doesn't happens.

Comment: I agree. For now I have gotten things working by ignoring it via NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0". At least I now know that my call is working.